# Replace tfa.metrics.F1Score from tf addon by tf.keras.metrics.F1Score

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have an old Kera model compiled with a custom model with [F1Score](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/metrics/F1Score) from Tensorflow Addon, as is deprecated now, I would like to migrate to [tf.keras.metrics.F1Score](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/F1Score) from the model saved.

This is what I used now when I load the model:

```py
   custom_objects = {
            'F1Score': F1Score(num_classes=4, threshold=0.5)
   }
```

I tried to replace it by the new function, but I get this message:

```
ValueError: Unable to restore custom object of class "Addons>F1Score" (type _tf_keras_metric). Please make sure that this class is included in the `custom_objects` arg when calling `load_model()`. Also, check that the class implements `get_config` and `from_config`.

Complete metadata: {'class_name': 'Addons>F1Score', 'name': 'f1_score', 'dtype': 'float32', 'config': {'name': 'f1_score', 'dtype': 'float32', 'num_classes': 4, 'average': None, 'threshold': 0.5}, 'shared_object_id': 32}
```

How can I do for migrating to the new function ?

Comment: If you replace tf-addons with new tf-keras API, why this `Addons>F1Score` appears in log message?

Comment: Hi @Innat, Is because on my original model I used the "Addons>F1score" so the logs told me then in my old model I used Addon, so I can't use a other class name on it

Comment: Could you load the old model with the `Addons>F1Score`, create a new model with the new `F1Score`, and copy the weights from the old model to the new one?Granted, this only works as long as you can use `Addons>F1Score`..